# To spell a word using words

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm wondering if there was a word that would describe: spelling out a word using a word

e.g.

Pear = Pineapple Energy Apple Red

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling_alphabet

Comment: @michael.hor257k is there a specific verb to describe this? Or would I just say: "Let me spell that out for you using phonetic alphabet"

Comment: I would say "Let me spell that phonetically." I don't know a single-word verb for it.

Comment: In circumstances where this kind of spelling is necessary or at least common, I have heard it as a single word: _spell_. In those situations, being asked to _spell_ "pear" would automatically result in an answer of _papa echo alpha romeo_. In other situations, it would simply have to be clarified, usually as _spell phonetically_, although that does conflict with phonetic spelling as in using _ipa_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **[Acrophony](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acrophony)** (noun) (M-W Dictionary)
>
> Definition of acrophony : the naming of a letter by a word whose
>   initial sound is the same as that which the letter represents.

(Wikipedia)

> "...the International Civil Aviation Organization (ICAO) alphabet
>   assigned codewords **[acrophonically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet)** to the letters of the
>   English alphabet, so that critical combinations of letters and numbers
>   are most likely to be pronounced and understood by those who exchange
>   voice messages by radio or telephone, regardless of language
>   differences or the quality of the communication channel".

**ICAO Code Words**

> A  Alfa / B  Bravo / C  Charlie/  D  Delta / E  Echo / F  Foxtrot / G 
>   Golf / H  Hotel / I  India / J  Juliett / K  Kilo / L  Lima / M  Mike
>   / N  November / O  Oscar / P  Papa / Q  Quebec / R  Romeo / S  Sierra
>   / T  Tango / U  Uniform / V  Victor / W  Whiskey / X  X-ray / Y 
>   Yankee / Z  Zulu /